# Writing a predicate for converting a float into a list of digits

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate that takes a float number and returns a list its digits. For example:

```
?- solA(0.1234, [], B).
B = [1,2,3,4]
```

This is my code:

```
 addhead(X, L, [X|L]).

 solA(0.0, _, _).
 solA(A, B, H) :-
     C is A*10,
     D is float_integer_part(C),
     E is round(D),
     F is C-E,
     addhead(E, B, G),
     solA(F, G, H).
```

Comment: You probably want `solA(0.0, G, G).` for your base case. `solA(0.0, _, _).` does not treat the `_` instances as the same variable. They're treated as two different anonymous variables. That may not be your only problem, but it's a significant one. You can also get rid of `addhead(E, B, G)` and replace the `G` in `solA(F, G, H)` with `solA(F, [E|B], H)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd solve it:

```
digits_of( Number , Digits ) :-
  number_codes( Number , Codes ) ,
  findall( Digit , ( member(Code,Codes) , digit(Code,Digit) ) ,Digits )
  .

digit(Code,Digit) :-
  code_type(Code,digit) ,
  Digit is Code - 48 , % 48 is code point for ASCII/Unicode zero ('0')
  .
```

Because dealing with floating point jitter gives me a headache.

Comment: An alternative to hardcode the code point of zero is to use `Digit is Code - 0'0`. You can also make the code more portable by using `Code >= 0'0, Code =< 0'9` instead of the proprietary predicate `code_type/2`.